# Make Bottom Border Closer To Text

Tags: css, border, margin

I want to underline my navigation menu but the problem is that I need it to be thicker so I am using bottom border instead so that I can set the width to 6px.

I can seem to figure out how to get the border to appear closer to the text. There seems to about a 10px gap between the text and the bottom-border at the moment and I don't want to have any.

I have tried to position another div and position it relative to each {li} with {bottom: 10px} but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I have so

CODE

```
    <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
position: fixed;
left: 25%;
clear: both;
float: left;
font-size: 80px;
z-index: 500;
filter: alpha(opacity=75);
opacity: .75;
}

#menu ul{
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 90px;
}

#menu ul li{
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
}

#menu ul li a{
border-bottom: 6px solid #000;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
color: #000;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a mixture of `line-height` and `margin` to garner such an effect, like so:

```
#menu ul li a {
    border-bottom: 6px solid #000000;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `display: inline-block;` in combination with `border-bottom` could cause some weird behavior  line breaks if longer links contain a line-break, see http://jsfiddle.net/PQZ9H/. Alternatively, you could use a combination of `background-image` and `background-position` which has the advantage of not touching the display value.

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==);
    background-position: left 15px;
}
a:hover { background: none; }
```

A disadvantage is that you might have to define a background-position for every font-size you use.

Using this technique you could also remove the border from descenders like g or y adding

```
a span.descender { text-shadow: -1px 0px 0px white, 1px 0px 0px white, -2px 0px 0px white, 2px 0px 0px white, -3px 0px 0px white, 3px 0px 0px white; }
```

and

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="descender">A link with descenders like g or y</span></a>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/25XNY/1

Comment: I've found that out of all the different options, using a background-image is by far the best. Also, by using em units instead of pixels, you do not have to worry about font size. For example `background-position: 0 1.05em;`

Comment: If we need a different color, go to [PNG Pixel - TRANSPARENT BASE64 PNG PIXEL GENERATOR](http://png-pixel.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Try to [this](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20120510/&act=url) (origin russian http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20120510/) article methods (background gradient and http://jsfiddle.net/d3WG6/)

```
<p>Зигварт считал <a><span>критерием истинности необходимость и&nbsp;общезначимость, для&nbsp;которых нет никакой опоры</span></a> в&nbsp;объективном мире.</p>

a { font-size: 50%; border-bottom: 1px dashed red; }
a > span { font-size: 200%; line-height: normal; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Margin property can't change the border-bottom position, so

**The height** of the `<a>` element will define the position of the your border-bottom.

```
 #menu > ul > li > a {
      height: ;
 }
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution for me.

Comment: The `line-height` works better in this case