# Display an icon from icon font as pseudo element in anchor with underline

Tags: css, fonts, icons, font-awesome

I want to display an "external" icon on any anchor elements that have the attribute rel="external". I was using an image originally, but this doesn't scale well with font-size and I want to minimise the amount of images we're using.

We use font-awesome for our other icons across the site, and usually include these with a specific icon element with the .fa-* class. However for external links I'd like to simply target them using CSS and apply the icon using the :after pseudo selector.

This is the CSS I have so far, and this is rendering correctly in iOS and Firefox, but in Chrome it is a pixel or two out, and the underline from the anchor is noticeably misaligned. I've used the [CSS content](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/) value with two spaces before it to include the icon.

```
a[rel="external"]:after {
  content: "\00a0\00a0\f08e";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing the behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/b9L3o5c5/2/

Does anybody know of a way to get this to display consistently across browsers? Or am I forced to revert back to using images?

Edit: I should've added that using a bottom border isn't an option as it doesn't allow for sufficicent control over how far away the border is from the bottom of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much as soon as I posted this I had a bit of a brainwave, and as I haven't found anything else on this I'll post the answer here.

If we use the after element to put some extra spaces after the text:

```
a[rel="external"]:after {
  content: '\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0';
}
```

And set the external links to be position relative, I can then set the icon to display as a :before element and absolutely position it to the right.

```
a[rel="external"] {
  position: relative;
}

a[rel="external"]:before {
  content: "\f08e";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here's a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/b9L3o5c5

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/b9L3o5c5/5/

```
html, body {

        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-size: 19px;
    }
```

You have to use the same fonts for body and icons and it works.

Comment: Using a border won't work I'm afraid as you can't control the distance between the bottom of the text and the border and it displays too far away. Thanks

Comment: Sorry this comment got duplicated. I can't set the body font-family to fontawesome as I'm using a different typeface in my actual solution

Comment: @hcharge if fonts are different then the space between the letters/signs and the line will be different. Same font is only sollution with that underline.

Comment: @hcharge yes it is and rated it up!. But my answer is also valid for the code without making new class.

Comment: Yes you're right, usually I wouldn't have had to worry, but this was bugging me! Thanks :-)

Comment: @hcharge Okay then! Glad to help. Please feel free to ask me whatever you want. Also thumb up is appreciate :)))

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to many browsers at the moment but I hope this works for you.

```
a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a[rel="external"]:after {
  content: "\00a0\00a0\f08e";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left: 1px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9L3o5c5/6/)

EDIT: In response to your comment, the only thing I can suggest is do it [with a background image.](http://jsfiddle.net/b9L3o5c5/10/) This idea was taken from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20588980/3984553)

Comment: Using a border won't work I'm afraid as you can't control the distance between the bottom of the text and the border and it displays too far away. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the positioning right, you should add all of the attributes that are normally provided by the class ".fa". ".fa" is doing a lot of positioning stuff under the hood.

If you are using something like sass (or a compass/burbon type framework), you may be able to simply '@include .fa' within your 'a[rel="external"]:after' specification.