# Make border-bottom closer to the text

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rd8n35do/)

**Try**
    I have applied line-height, display properties. But none of these works fine with double lined text.

```css
.container span {
  width:80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.container {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>My Cash & Discounts</span>
  (0)
</div>
```

[I have found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131713/make-bottom-border-closer-to-text).
But it's not working fine.

Ques:
   Please take a look at my fiddle. How to make border-bottom to match with text-underline? How to remove the gap between that two lines?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this, instead of simply setting a border of style `double`?

Comment: Do you want only one line instead of double line?

Comment: Or are you actually trying to make the border and the underline a single line? Why not set a border with the desired width then?

Comment: Ipad dosn't support text-decoration color property. So i am using border instead of that.

Comment: What are you looking for specifically?

Comment: Text-decoration with different color. but it should be supported in all the browsers, devices.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert another container:

```
<div class="container">
    <span><span class="inner">My Cash &amp; Discounts</span></span>
    (0)
</div>
```

And assign a negative value for `margin-bottom`:

```
.container span
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display:inline-block;
}

.container span.inner {
    border:none;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:-3px;
}

.container
{
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: No. I need underline in both line of texts. No only at the last line.